# Remove all previous text before writing

Tags: c#-4.0, stream, streamwriter

I am writing a text file and each time i write i want to **clear** the text file.

```
try
{
    string fileName = "Profile//" + comboboxSelectProfile.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".txt";
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(("Default//DefaultProfile.txt").ToString(), true))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(fileName);
        MessageBox.Show("Default is set!");
    }
    DefaultFileName = "Default//DefaultProfile.txt";
}
catch 
{ 
}
```

How do I do this? I want to remove all previous content from **DefaultProfile.txt**.

I actually have to know the method or way (just a name could be) to remove all content from the text file.

Comment: A easy way could be to get the data, delete the file and create a new one. Is there any better way?

Comment: I think this is a simpler [Solution][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24933010/2374691

Answer (score 24):

You could just write an empty string to the existing file:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"Default\DefaultProfile.txt", string.Empty);
```

Or change the second parameter in the `StreamWriter` constructor to `false` to *replace* the file contents instead of *appending* to the file.

Answer (score 18):

You can look at the **Truncate** method

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"Default\DefaultProfile.txt");
using(TextWriter txtWriter = new StreamWriter(fi.Open(FileMode.Truncate)))
{
    txtWriter.Write("Write your line or content here");
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The most straightforward and efficient technique is to use the StreamWriter constructor's boolean parameter.  When it's set to false it overwrites the file with the current operation.  For instance, I had to save output of a mathematical operation to a text file.  Each time I wanted ONLY the current answer in the text file.  So, on the first StreamWriter operation, I set the boolean value to false and the subsequent calls had the bool val set to true.  The result is that for each new operation, the previous answer is overwritten and only the new answer is displayed.

```
        int div = num1 / denominator;
        int mod = num1 % denominator;
        Console.Write(div);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, false ))
        {
            writer.Write(div);
        }
        Console.Write(".");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, true))
        {
            writer.Write(".");
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `FileMode.Truncate`. Code will look like

```
FileStream fs = new 
FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Truncate, FileAccess.Write )
{  
  fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the second parameter from `true` to `false` in the contructor of `StreamWriter`.

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(("Default//DefaultProfile.txt").ToString(), **false**))
```

See [StreamWriter Contructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_)

Answer (score 1):

`System.IO.File.Delete`, or one of the `System.IO.FileStream` constructor overloads specifying `FileMode.Create`